# Respond to the right client in a Reverse proxy

Tags: go

I'm trying to build a persistent TCP connection between two servers using Go; A `client` that resides locally and `server` in the remote machine. The client also serves HTTP requests locally to a `PHP` script. Each request is relayed through the TCP connection to the remote server. The response is then sent back to the PHP script.

```
HTTP request from .php script
  \
   \    -----> HTTP req is relayed
    \                 
client <--------------TCP connection------------> server
    / 
   /              <------ Response is relayed
  /
HTTP request from .php script
```

With concurrent connections, the requests sent to and back from the remote server aren't synchronized, i.e. the response for request #1 could be sent to request #2 instead.

**My current solution**

I've created a `map` of channels that are identified by a unique ID per HTTP request. This unique ID is passed in the TCP request to the server and is sent back along with the response. The client parses this ID in the response and sends it to the corresponding channel in the array. Oversimplified code where `conns` is the `map` of available channels and the unique ID is the whole response, or `str`:

```
    connbuf := bufio.NewReader(remoteConn)  
    str, err := connbuf.ReadString('\n')
    str = strings.TrimSpace(str)
    if len(str) > 0 {
        id, _ := strconv.Atoi(str)
        conns[id] <- str
    }
```

**Question**

Is there a more elegant, built-in way to achieve this - making sure requests and responses to the local PHP script are correct even with concurrent requests?

Comment: Given the task of multiplexing a bunch of reqs onto one connection, then yeah, seems inevitable you wind up with something roughly as complex as what you're doing.

Comment: Any pointers on how to do this reliably? Any best-practices on implementing this (in any other lang will help understand as well)?

Comment: Using the `multiplexing` keyword you mentioned, I found this: https://github.com/inconshreveable/muxado and this by the same author http://www.hakkalabs.co/articles/stream-multiplexing-go  Do you think this fixes this @twotwotwo

Comment: Ah, that's great, I hadn't even expected that comment would help much! Yes, I've only peeked at that package, but it does look like it's for the kind of task you've described here; seems worth trying to integrate.

Comment: This solves my issue.. If you can post that as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: @twotwotwo Could you please provide an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is as much a self-answer by kouton as anything, but using a single "back end" connection (between your local server and the remote server) to service multiple "front end" connections (between your local PHP and the local server) is a form of *multiplexing*, and the [muxado](https://github.com/inconshreveable/muxado) package ([video of a talk](https://www.hakkalabs.co/articles/stream-multiplexing-go)) is meant to help you implement it.